# Does long support decimals?

Tags: excel, vba, byval

I was trying to make sense of ByVal and ByRef and passing arguments from long to double using the ByVal keyword.

I noticed that VBA gave me the incorrect answer for the value of y squared. It *does* work when y (i in my sub) is a whole number.

In the below example I had i = 22.5.
The spreadsheet gave me 506.25.
My function gave me 484.

I thought both long and double support decimals.

```
Sub automation_test()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim ans As Long

i = Range("B1")
j = Range("B2")
x = Range("B3")

ans = my_model(i, j, x)

Range("B4").Value = ans

End Sub


Function my_model(ByVal y As Double, ByVal m As Double, ByVal q As Double) As Double

' my_model = (y ^ 2) * (m ^ 3) * (q ^ 1 / 2)

my_model = y ^ 2

End Function
```

Comment: Long variable does not accept decimals! Since you do not use the variables used like arguments, after calling the function,`ByVal` does not make any difference against `ByRef`... Try declaring all variables 'As Double`, please. And it is good to use `i = Range("B1").value`. VBA is able to guess what is it about, but it is good to cultivate such a habit to visually differentiate from using it like range.

Comment: ByVal and ByRef are used for API calls. For strings ByVal sends a C string and ByRef sends a VB string, API calls want C strings. For other types you always use ByVal for in parameters (so the function you are calling doesn't mess with your variables) and ByRef for out parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare all used variables `As Double` (or `As Single`, depending on the maximum value to be used).

`Long` variables do not accept decimals.

The difference is exactly the one coming from rounding (down):

`22.5^2 = 506.25`

`22^2 = 484`